# How to bind multiple check-boxes values to a property of the model in Mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 @Html.CheckBox("WiFi", @Model.Amenities.Contains("WiFi"))
  @Html.CheckBox("Dining", @Model.Amenities.Contains("Dining"))
```

Using this format I am able to get the values from sql server but not able to bind them with the property.

It seems weird but I entered the values of the attribute Amenities directly into the db. I want to use html helper only.

Comment: Does you model have properties `bool WiFi` and `bool Dining`? I think you might be misunderstanding `@Html.CheckBox`

Comment: I am having only one property in the model for checkboxes that is Amenities. I want to bind all the values of these checkboxes to the Amenities.

Comment: What you want is radio buttons - I'll post an answer shortly

Comment: Actually I'm working on an old project on mvc. My senior had implemented input fields of type "checkbox". I want to use html helpers instead. Using input fields he was able to get the values of all checked check-boxes and store them into the  "string Amenities {get; set;}". The field in the db is of type string. we are not using bool.

Comment: Yes I know. Check my answer shortly (checkboxes are for binding to boolean values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to bind a range of possible values to property `Amenities`, use radio buttons (checkboxes are for binding to boolean values)

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Amenities, "WiFi")<span>WiFi</span>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Amenities, "Dining")<span>Dining</span>
// More radio buttons for other possible values that you want to set for Amenities
```

This will create a series of radio buttons allowing you to set the value of `Amenities` from one of the options ("WiFi", "Dining" etc) and if the initial value of `Amenities` is say "Dining", when the view is rendered, the 2nd radio button will be selected

PS. Always use the strongly typed version of html helpers - `@Html.CheckBoxFor()`, not `@Html.CheckBox()`

Comment: But this way I'm not able to select both of them.  They should be stored  in form of a string.

Comment: In that case you need `@Html.ListBoxFor()` with a `SelectList` to allow you to select multiple values, or create a series of properties in you view model `bool IsWiFi`, `bool IsDining` etc so they can be bound to checkboxes, or manually extract the checkbox values from `FormCollection` and build the string as you must be currently doing

Comment: I don't have bool Wifi. I have string Amenities in which the values which have been ticked will be stored.

Comment: I know, but you are not understanding how model binding works. You cant bind to a property which does not exist! `@Html.CheckBox("WiFi", ..)` creates `<input type="checkbox" name="WiFi" ..>` Note the name attribute ("WiFi"). When this posts back it tries to find a property in your model with the name `WiFi` which does not exist so nothing is bound. Your options are to use javascript to dynamically create the value or use `FormCollection` to inspect the keys and manually create the string for `Amenities'

Comment: That is why I was trying to find out some other way. I have 22 checkboxes and I don't want to make 22 bool properties inside the model. May be I'll have to use input field option only which was used earlier in the project. But anyways thanks for your help.